# IntelliJ scroll console to end after test execution

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

This is a little thing that annoys me. When I run a test case, output console is flooded by messages (especially when testing Spring beans). When test finishes, I see the red bar appearing, I see that there is a stacktrace somewhere down, but the output is immediately moved to the top.

I know that there is a 'Scroll to the end' button, but I have to click it. I want the end of a test output to be displayed automatically.

I'm using IntelliJ CE, 2018.3.2

I'm attaching a screenshot that shows my console after executing a failing test. Despite a 'Scroll to the end' button is enabled, output is "rewind" to top.

[image]

Comment: ...but that *is* the end of the test output.  It includes everything from STDOUT and STDERR.  That is, unless you want to *suppress* all test logging messages...and even then that'd have to be configured in your build script (either Maven or Gradle).

Comment: Makoto, it's not exactly what I want. Pay close attention when test is run. What happens is that a lot of messages appear on a console, test ends, you can see for a half a second or so that there is some error/exception/whatever, and then immediately console is scrolled to the top. So if I want to see that stacktrace I have to scroll down.

Comment: Is it possible to share short screencast? Console is scrolled to the end on my machine. By the way, what IDE version do you use?

Answer (score 23):

For me (in webstorm 2020) the solution was to click the cog wheel, then select `Scroll to Stack Trace`. I'm sure in all the Jetbrains products this is the solution.
[image]

Comment: Upvoted because I had missed the "Scroll to Stack Trace" option. Better but does not always work. For example, I can see the stack trace immediately after running the test, but if I navigate between tests, it will scroll all the way up again (IntelliJ 2020.1.2)

Comment: This is the solution.

Comment: For me, I had to select `Scroll to Stack Trace` and unselect `Track running test` (for single test run)

Comment: I can confirm that @PD solution works in Goland as well

Answer (score 20):

Ok, I found some kind of solution. In the test run tab, there is an icon for test settings. In there there is an option `'Track running test'`. I noticed that when I change this setting, my console output stays at the botton and it's not being rewind. You can see that on a screenshot below.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is IntelliJ's feature or a bug, but maybe someone will find this post useful.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for a long time. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me. It still does the same thing.

Comment: I realized I had the `Idealog` plugin enabled, and thought that might be causing problems. I tried disabling it, but there was no difference. If I run my failing test dozens of times, maybe 20% of the time the console will be waiting at the bottom. Every other time I have to reach for the keyboard and/or mouse to see the failure message. The behavior is very inconsistent. 2009.1.1. I should file a ticket...

Comment: Is it when you run a single test case or whole suite?

Comment: It was a single test in this case.

Comment: For me, for a single test use case, unchecking `Track running test` worked for me

Comment: What worked for me is to select "Select first failed test when finished" in the test panel settings.  Thank you @mate00 for pointing me in the right direction!!

Comment: Super, I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thank you for coming back and writing the solution, it worked for me, it drove me crazy, and it seems like a bug

Comment: These don't work for me. "Track running test" doesn't seem to be present in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 (Community Edition). There is "show console when stdout is written to"~, but that is only during the test run. I created this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281539

Comment: this one worked for me,  i had both "track running tests" unchecked and "scroll to stack trace" checked